# How to manage eclipse git authority?

Tags: java, eclipse, git, merge, authorization

I am working on a java web application project with Eclipse.

My team uses Git(which is basically included in Eclipse Luna) as a code merging tool.

What I want to do is separate authority by users. like github.com.
(As you know, people commit their soucecode in local repository and request 'pull request' to Super user. Than only SuperUser can merging the source.)

But I can not find any authority option in Eclipse GUI.

Is there any links or tutorials for 'Eclipse git authority options'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, git itself (or EGit for Eclipse) doesn't provide ACL (Access Control Level) based on authorization, since it would involve authentication.

Eclipse is not involve in authorizing a push or not: this is a control done on the server side (where a listener like Apache or ssh will call git in order to update a repo pushed by a developer, from his/her git command-line interface or from Eclipse)

It is on the server that you need to add an **[authorization layer](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/concepts.html)** (like [gitolite](http://gitolite.com/)) in order to control the right to push/pull/clone a repo.

Comment: Thanks for specific explanation. now I got it! bb